# Are there any video cards that support UEFI GOP?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a [Motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?cat=Download&os=BIOS&Model=990FX%20Extreme4) that has a "Ultra Fast start-up mode". For this feature your video card needs to support "UEFI GOP". I was searching for Video cards that support it, but I can’t find any. I want to buy a [AMD HD7850](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007JCNOZK), are there any HD7850 that support EUFI GOP? or aren't there Video cards with that?

Comment: http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=370375

Comment: There are a few working cards listed in this [German forum thread](http://forum.pctreiber.net/threads/15275-Grafikkarten-UEFI-GOP-Support-Liste) Seems like support is slim to none. Some people report that the manufacturer provided them with updated BIOS sets for their card.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but maybe this was closed because it seems too much like a request for a "shopping or product recommendation" (see http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).  Personally, I would leave this question open because it addresses the state-of-the-art in desktop computer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  There is support for UEFI Graphics Output Protocol in the HD 7850.

The Card is Gigabyte HD 7850 OC, which is officially supported UEFI. This means ultra-fast Windows 8 Booting!