# No display when discrete graphics card inserted

Tags: graphics-card, bios, uefi, integrated-graphics

I recently purchased a new desktop PC: HP p7-1423w, i5-3330, HD Graphics 2500 (integrated).  The first thing I did was remove Windows 8 and install Linux.  A few days later, I was ready to install a graphics card that I already owned (NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 610 -- PCI Express 2.0).

*When I insert the graphics card and turn on power, I get beeping and there is no display from either the discrete or the integrated graphics.*

I can remove the card and work with the BIOS, but **there isn't any setting that seems like it would improve this situation**.

I actually had the same problem a few days earlier with a totally different computer (Gateway/AMD), which I decided to return.  This makes me think that the problem relates to Windows 8 and the newer "UEFI" BIOS associated with that.

Are there known problems and solutions for installing discrete graphics in computers that are designed for Windows 8 but now run only Linux?

Comment: The problem arose not because of Win8 but because you used an old graphics card (the 610 is just a rebranded 520) that doesn't support UEFI.

Comment: @Karan: Thanks for the info.  Is this what you are talking about: [Are there any video cards that support UEFI GOP?](http://superuser.com/questions/537320/are-there-any-video-cards-that-support-uefi-gop)

Comment: Yeah. Also see my comment [here](http://superuser.com/questions/494303/is-is-possible-to-update-bios-to-uefi#comment601225_501871). *Perhaps* there's a similar UEFI update available for your card, but I highly doubt it (not much incentive to do so, even if the ROM size is adequate).

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it to work by going into the **security menu** of the BIOS and setting the following:

- Secure Boot: Disable
- Legacy support: Enable

Other notes:

- I had already disabled the "Secure Boot" option in order to install Linux.
- There was a scary red warning box that told me that these settings only affect Windows 8.
- I do not know if this solution is compatible with running Windows 8 (e.g. dual boot).
- BIOS menus tend to not be very user friendly.

There are some other sources that provide this solution, but they are hard to find if you don't know that the problem specifically correlates to "Windows 8".

- [When installing an after-market graphics card into a certified Windows 8 PC with UEFI enabled, the system may not boot.](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3156/~/when-installing-an-after-market-graphics-card-into-a-certified-windows-8-pc)
- [No video at POST, Windows 8 prebuilt system with Secure Boot](http://www.evga.com/support/faq/afmviewfaq.aspx?faqid=59421)
- [Computer Does not Start After Installing a Video Card (Windows 8)](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03653200)

Comment: Funny story: A year and a half later, I wanted to boot Windows 8 (for the first time).  I disconnected my Linux drive and reconnected my Windows drive.  I get Error code 0xc0000001 "Your PC couldn't start properly" and it tells me to insert the install media, which I don't think I have.  I resolved this by reverting the BIOS settings *and* removing the graphics card (which is a brand new one).  I think it wanted to do the initial PC setup with the initial hardware.