# Query about Graphics card and UEFI Support

Tags: graphics-card, uefi, secure-boot

I am trying to better understand graphics cards and UEFI support. Some related post seems to be [here](https://superuser.com/questions/594757/no-display-when-discrete-graphics-card-inserted/594758#594758) on this forum as well.

It seems there are graphics cards that have UEFI Support. My understanding is that opting for such a card would be necessary if you intend to run your system in UEFI mode. i.e. you keep 'Legacy Mode' disabled.

However  does  ‘UEFI Supported’ graphics card run fine when ‘Secure Boot’ is enabled in addition to UEFI?
Thanks.

Comment: Secure boot has no connection to a GPU.

Comment: That depends on how the firmware is set up. Booting via the CSM ("legacy support") necessarily bypasses Secure Boot. Despite this, some computers let you enable both Secure Boot and the CSM, even though (IIRC) the spec disallows this. I've seen one or two implementations that let you selectively enable the CSM, so it's active *only* for plug-in cards' option ROMs. In the end, therefore, you'll need to study your own computer's options and perhaps just try it to see what it does.